# how can show list as like tablview in phonegap javascript?

Tags: javascript, cordova

HTML:

```
<ul id="listview" data-inset="true"></ul>
```

JavaScript:

```
for(i=0;i<titles.length;i++){
    $('#listview').append('<li><a href="#">'+titles[i]+'</a>      </li>');
}
```

it will show simle list but i need listview as tableview?

Comment: You don't have any `script` tags.

Comment: yes ..am showing only functionality only

Comment: What do you mean by "show listview as tableview" ?

Comment: in boday section am write code as <ul id="listview" data-inset="true"></ul>

Comment: by using for loop am display titles names in listview but instad that i need like http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.0/docs/widgets/listviews/  sample

Comment: Are you using jQuery Mobile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PhoneGap isn't a wrapper to compile your JS / HTML into Objective-C style code. I assume that what you want to achieve is something similar to the following image:

[image]

You will need to style your `#listview` using CSS to achieve this. For example, you might try something like this:

```
#listview {
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

    #listview li {
        width: 100%;
        padding: 10px;
        font-weight: bold;
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
                box-sizing: border-box;
        background-color: #fff;
        float: left;
        clear: both;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    }
        #listview li:last-of-type {
            border-bottom: none;
        }
```

Comment: @Benm...perfect answer thanks a lot and also need > for all listview

Comment: i need set default image for cell ? can pls give a idea or code to display that image with name ???